# Maven: mvn test gives error + Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, testng

Running testng.xml directly from eclipse IDE, test suite gets executed but on executing testng.xml from maven gives error.

Running `mvn compile`, it says BUILD SUCCESS. But on running `mvn test`it gives error.

On running maven script through `mvn test` I am receiving below error:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ XXX
--
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) @ XXX---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: \XXX\target\surefire-reports
Running TestSuite
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.295 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-09T17:34:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/208M

--------------------
-----------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
18:test (default-test) on project XXX: Exception in provider:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.XXX.tests.XXXX.classtoexecute
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project XXX: Exception in provider
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
```

Please help.

Below is POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xx.tests</groupId>
  <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <configuration>
          <forkCount>0</forkCount>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>atu.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>reports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

TestNg is as belwo:

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="XXXX" parallel="none" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener"></listener>
    </listeners>
  <test name="test1" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.XXX.tests.XXXX.classtoexecute"/>
    </classes>
 </test> 
</suite>
```

The project structure is as below:
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: You should start by updating your testng dependency to 6.9.9 and surefire to 2.19. Then, sharing your testng.xml may help.

Comment: Do you confirm that com.xxxx.tests.XXX.XXXX is located into the src/test/java directory?

Comment: @juherr : Yes it is in same

Comment: TestNG has been added as edit

Comment: Updating to 6.9.9 and 2.19 results into same error

Comment: Where is testng.xml , move it => src/test/resources ?

Comment: In your files, are `com.xxxx.tests.XXX.XXXX` and `com.XXX.tests.XXXX.classtoexecute` the same class? You should try to reproduce the problem on a minimal project you can share without obfuscation.

Comment: @juherr. Yes.. They are same classes. I tried with one class only project and maven was working fine.

Comment: @question_maven_com: testng.xml is at root path. I am implementing POM hence, I dont have segregation like main and test. I have pages packages which has class for different page of web application and I have tests pages which has test cases related to those pages. Attached is project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting non-maven to maven worked for my test project.

```
right click on project->Configure->Convert it to Maven
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a same project structure as you described. Copied pom.xml as it is. Below are some steps I took to make it execute the required class.

1. I put `testng.xml` directly in project's root folder i.e. on same level of `pom.xml`.
2. Next in `testng.xml` I wrote

   ```
   <classes>
         <class name="com.Local.Tests.TestClass"/>
   </classes>
   ```

   Check the package name in Java file at the beginning.
3. Run as `mvn test`.

I could see my selenium tests executing successfully.

```
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\workspace\TestngPOM\target\surefire-reports
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.659 sec
```

Give it a try.

This is how my maven project structure.[image]

Comment: I tried the same. Created a whole new project but it still gives same error that it can not find class in classpath while executing it as testng is working fine.

Comment: I can see your edited screenshot. Did you convert existing project to maven? To execute test class files, maven searches it in `src/test/java` followed by your own package structure. If it is not, then maven will fail to find the test class.

Comment: Yes I have added POM.xml later to execute testng from maven but no luck. How can I execute it in this case ?

Comment: How did you convert it? Like `right click on project->Configure->Convert it to Maven`? Simply adding `pom.xml` on top of non-maven project may not work. I suggest you to create a simple maven project from eclipse, which will give you the project structure I shared. I follow further steps.

Comment: I added pom.xml with all plugins, dependencies detail. I did same in another project too and it had worked fine, But I am receiving error in this case.

Comment: Ok, I also did the same thing. i.e. converted `non-maven project` to `Maven`. Try adding `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` under `<build>` in `pom.xml`. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Converting non-maven to maven worked for my test project. I will check for my POC and will update the post. Thanks all fro your time and patience.

Comment: I've mix of Java tests & few Scala tests. When I run them using TestNG.xml (right click & click run as TestNG test, in IntelliJ) then they are running fine. But when I do mvn test then its giving ' Cannot find class in classpath: Scala.RestTest.scala' for scala tests

Answer (score 0):

i had same error,

Move your src folder to Main > Java

it should be "`src > Main > Java`"  >

```
com.something.test.something

com.something.test.sometest2
```

now compile/run in maven

Comment: Everything only used for testing in Maven is usually placed in `src/test/` to separate it from the code in `src/main`